# What does " # " mean in Erlang?

Tags: syntax, erlang

What does "#" mean in Erlang syntax?

For example:

```
 Request#radius_packet.attrs
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hash marks can mean two things in Erlang: reference to a record, or reference to a map.

The specific case above is referencing a record with the variable name `Request`, of the type `radius_packet`, and accessing field `attrs`. This syntax mimics accessing a field on a struct or object in other languages (but be careful because it is *not* the same). It is directly equivalent to referencing that field as part of a variable assignment and then using the variable. The three versions of `some_function/1` below are all equivalent in terms of what they pass to `do_something/1`:

```
some_function(Request = #radius_packet{attrs = Attrs}) ->
    do_something(Attrs),
    % Other things where we need Request also...

some_function(#radius_packet{attrs = Attrs}) ->
    do_something(Attrs),
    % Other things where we don't need Record...

some_function(Request) ->
    do_something(Request#radius_packet.attrs),
    % etc...
```

Records are a meta-syntax; they are a preprocessor convenience which is actually translated to tuples before compilation (which is why records are so fast). So given the following definition of `#radius_packet{}` the following version of `some_function` is exactly equivalent to the ones above:

```
-record #radius_packet{serial, headers, attrs}.

some_function({radius_packet, _, _, Attrs}) ->
    do_something(Attrs),
    % Other things where we don't need Record...
```

The above version has simply ignored record syntax in favor of writing out the underlying tuple that will be created by the preprocessor.

[Erlang docs page on records.](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html)

The other place you will see hashes is in maps. Map syntax using hashes looks similar to record syntax, but without any type name between the hash and the opening curley bracket:

```
AMap#{}
ARecord#record_type{}
```

[Erlang docs page on map expressions.](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81375)

Answer (score 6):

`Request` is the variable the record is bound to.

`#` denotes the variable is a record.

`radius_packet` is the name of the record.

`attrs` is the field you're accessing from the record.